# What event is fired when Google Map repaints?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

What event is fired when Google Maps repaint itself?  For example when you zoom in or out?

I have an info window open and when it repaints I lose it. I'm using JQuery to load the map on Document.Ready()

Comment: That's odd, I have a google maps application and the info windows do not go away when I change the zoom level.

Comment: Could you show me the code you use to populate the if window?  this is the first time I've used google maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use the [tilesloaded](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2.tilesloaded) event, but if you want to know specifically when the zoom is changed, you can use the [zoomend](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2.zoomend) event.

```
GEvent.addListener(map, "tilesloaded", function() { 
  //...
}); 

GEvent.addListener(map, "zoomend", function (oldZoom, newZoom) { 
  //...
});
```

Check this [example](http://jsbin.com/orejo).